# In Wittgenstein's Picture theory, why is self-awareness (e.g. Cogito ergo sum in Descartes) not an a priori true atomic thought?

Tags: wittgenstein, descartes

3.04 An a priori true thought would be one whose possibility guarenteed its truth.

Note: I am asking about the earlier Wittgenstein and not his post-Tractatus philosophy.

It is clear to me why this is not an a priori true *fact*, as the act of thinking would be an aspect of the world being appealed to. But I don't understand why it is not an a priori true *thought*.

Comment: "true thought" as in it is an actual thought (proposition with a sense per TLP) or a thought that's propositional content is true? Welcome to philosophy.SE!

Comment: 3.04 sounds strikingly like the ontological argument for existence, stripped of it's religious nature.

Comment: In *Tractatus* a thought is not an "act of the mind", but a "thought content". Compare with G.Frege, [The Thought: A Logical Inquiry](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2251513?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (1918).

Comment: "*a priori* true fact" is not W... True are thought and propositions that "picture" the facts.

Comment: See also Juliette Floyd, [The Frege-Wittgenstein Correspondence](http://www.bu.edu/philo/files/2011/01/Frege-WittCorrespondence.pdf) for the relation between W's *Tractatus* and later Frege, specifically *The Thought*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing is, that for the early Wittgenstein the Cogito Ergo Sum was just [not true](http://www.kfs.org/jonathan/witt/t563en.html). So the Cogito could not be true *a priori* for him.

Like David Hume, Wittgenstein believed that the Cartesian Ego, the thinking subject, was nowhere to be found.

> 5.631 **There is no such thing as the subject that thinks or entertains ideas**. If I wrote a book called The World as l found it , I should have to include a report on my body, and should have to say which parts were subordinate to my will, and which were not, etc., this being a method of isolating the subject, or rather of showing that in an important sense there is no subject; for it alone could not be mentioned in that book.

The self exists only as an external "limit" of the linguistically constructed world. (Perhaps akin to Kant's Transcendental Subject)

> 5.632 The subject does not belong to the world: rather, it is a limit of the world.

And again

> 5.641... **The philosophical self is not the human being, not the human body, or the human soul**, with which psychology deals, but rather the metaphysical subject, the limit of the world — not a part of it.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that there is no place for *a priori* knowledge in the [Tractatus](https://people.umass.edu/klement/tlp/tlp.pdf) (quoting from Pears/McGuinness translation).

Some basic concepts are : form, possibility, picture.

> **3** A logical picture of facts is a thought.

Here I read "thought" in a Fregean way, as "thought content" (and not as an act of the mind).

A picture can represent reality in virtue of its (logical or pictorial) form (**2.17**).

> **2.11** A picture presents a situation in logical space, the existence and non-existence of states of affairs [see also **2.202**].

Thus, we have thoughts that "represent" possible situations [their *sense*; see **2.221**] and *true* thoughts that represent "actual" situations: *facts* (**2.222** and **3.01**).

> **2.225** There are no pictures that are true a priori.

Now for

> **3.04** If a thought were correct a priori, it would be a thought whose possibility ensured its truth.

This is reminiscent of the well-known [ontological arguments](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ontological-arguments/): a *concept* (or *thought*) that "analytically" entails the existence of an object that falls under the concept; whose possibility implies its actuality.

> **3.05** A priori knowledge that a thought was true would be possible only if its truth were recognizable from the thought itself (without anything to compare it with).

Thus, it seems that there are no *a priori* truth.

> **5.133** All deductions are made a priori.

This fits with the "tautological" nature of logic: logic "transform" but not "produce" truth and knowledge [see also: **5.4731** What makes logic a priori is the impossibility of illogical thought.]

And:

> **5.134** One elementary proposition cannot be deduced from another.

I.e. there is no knowledge by "logic alone" of the contingent facts of the world. See also :

> **5.557** The application of logic decides what elementary propositions
>   there are. [...]
>
> **5.5571** If I cannot say a priori what elementary propositions there are, then the attempt to do so must lead to obvious nonsense.

Now for the *cogito*: in Descartes it is not a *deduction* but an *intuition*. If so, it must be modelled in Tractarian's philosophy as an *elementary proposition*, that cannot be deduced from another.

If it is true, it is so by way of its picturing a *fact*.

But a picture is always contingent: there are no a priori pictures.

Thus, it can be (at most) the "empirical" recognition of a contingent fact.